# Makefile secondary expansion: execution of escaped function?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, variable-expansion

Consider the following makefile:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

%.result: jobs/% $$(call get-job,$$<)
    echo $^

define get-job
$(shell head -n 1 $(1))
$(shell tail -n +2 $(1))
endef
```

The idea is that each file under *jobs/* contains a list of filenames, which should be appended to the prerequisite list.

However, if I want to create *xyz.result* from an existing file *jobs/xyz*, I get the following error message:

```
$ make -n xyz.result
head: cannot open 'xyz.result' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: cannot open 'xyz.result' for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open 'xyz.result' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: cannot open 'xyz.result' for reading: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'xyz.result'. Stop.
```

I am aware that `$$<` isn't set to what I want, as it reflects the prerequisite list of any previous rule.
What I don't understand is the following:

- In my understanding, `$$<` should evaluate to the empty string (as shown in the example in the [official doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion), under the second sub-heading). However, it seems to be expanded to the value of the target here (*xyz.result*). Why is that?
- It seems that the `get-job` function is called twice (`head` and `tail` both bark twice). I understand that the prerequisite list is expanded twice. But in the first run, the `call` is still escaped, so this isn't what I expect.

(Maybe the whole approach is flawed, and I shouldn't be (ab)using Makefile for this kind of task in the first place.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why `$$<` expands that way.

You can make your configuration work by using `$$*` instead, though:

```
%.result: jobs/% $$(strip $$(call get-job,jobs/$$*))
        echo $^
```

You need to add the `strip` call so that the newlines embedded in the results of the `call` will be turned into spaces.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I don't understand why, though – do you have any idea why not calling `strip` causes `get-job` to be executed twice? Those newlines originate from the `head` and `tail`, after all...

Comment: It doesn't get called twice.  It gets called once.  However, newlines embedded in a `define`...`endef` are preserved.  So there's a newline between the output of the first shell command and the second shell command.  You could write it like this instead: `get-job = $(shell head -n 1 $(1)) $(shell tail -n +2 $(1))` without using `define`, then you wouldn't need the `strip` call.

Comment: I see. But then why do I get two error messages each from `head` and `tail`?

Comment: I don't know why you do... I can't reproduce that.  I get one error message each for `head` and `tail`, not two, when I use your original test.

Comment: Ok, maybe I don't want to know anyway :-p.